# rails passing multiple params to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inherited-resources

I have a route for querying "Service" model:

```
resources :services, :path => 'services'
```

When GET requests for path `/services/sn-uber` i take param sn(service name) and find it in database. How to add there another param like sd(service-district)?

For example `/services/sn-uber/sd-brooklyn` or `/services/sd-brooklyn` so any param could be omitted.

Comment: Your question is not clear. As per my understanding from your question. You can pass multiple params like `/services/sn-uber?service-district=sd-brooklyn`

Comment: Yes, with query params I can do it easily, but how to do without them? (for SEO purposes)

Comment: `/services/:id(/:id_2)` it will allow you to pass 2 or one id in this route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add something like this to your routes:

```
get 'services(/sn/:sn_name)(/sd/:sd_name)', controller: 'services', action: 'show'
```

Your url will look like:

- `/services/sn/uber/sd/brooklyn`

  - params will be `sn_name` and `sd_name`
- `/services/sn/uber`

  - param will be `sn_name`
- `/services/sd/brooklyn`

  - param will be `sd_name`

If you want to keep your url like that `/services/sn-uber/sd-brooklyn`:

```
get 'services(/:sn_name)(/:sd_name)', controller: 'services', action: 'show'
```